# Update map in-place

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a piece of code manipulating a `map<int,int>` object. Let's say that at some point I want to double all the entries, keys and values. Is a there a way to do it in place, without creating a new map, looping and entering updated entries?

My concern is saving memory space.

Comment: Please show your code, note that modifying thy keys of a map will invalidate any iterators being used as the map has to be reordered, also why would you want to modify the key in such a way? Are you sure you want a `map` for this?

Comment: I don't think, even if you find something like this, that it would save a lot of memory or processing power. In the end most of these functions are just doing what you want to avoid in the background.

Comment: Your problem isn't well defined. Doubling a key could give you the key of an element that already exists. Which value would you then double?

Comment: I think no. The better way is building a new map and filling elements of the current map. You'll have only n insert operations instead of n deletions and n insertions.

Comment: No. You cannot change the keys of map elements.

Comment: What are you using this `map` for anyway? Are you sure it isn't better to just have a `vector` of `pair<int, int>`?

Comment: That's like asking if you can modify a phone book to change both all the names and numbers in-place. But then you wouldn't really be changing anything, you'd just end up with a different phone book.

Comment: How big is this map?  A `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` sorted by the first int in the pair would take **much** less space than a std::map (and would make the operation trivial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubling the values is possible like this:

```
std::map<int,int> my_map;
for(auto& item:my_map){
    item.second*=2; // double all values
}
```

However, it is not possible to double the `Key` since `item` is from the type `std::pair<const int,int>`. Notice the `const` for the `Key`.

**Suggestion**:

I think `std::map` is not best container for this case. Try this way:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> my_simi_map;
for(auto& my_simi_map){
    item.first*=2; // double all keys
    item.second*=2; // double all values
}
```

**Edit:**

> My concern is saving memory space.

If it is just memory problem then you can pick an item from the map and insert a doubled version of it in the new map and directly delete it from the old map. In this case you will loose the size of just one element of the map not a whole another map.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the map in reverse order of key for positive keys, in order to circumvent side effects, and create the new key/value pairs. You can do the equivalent for negative keys.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  map<int, int> m = {
    {10, 20},
    {-5, 23},
    {-10, 7},
    {20, 30},
    {15, 21},
    {18, 2},
  };

  for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end() && it->first < 0; it = m.erase(it)) {
    m[it->first * 2] = 2 * it->second;
  }

  for (auto it = m.rbegin(); it != m.rend() && it->first > 0; it++) {
    m[it->first * 2] = 2 * it->second;
    m.erase(----it.base());
  }

  for (auto &p: m) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", p.first, p.second);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
-20, 14
-10, 46
20, 40
30, 42
36, 4
40, 60
```